# NullPointer Exception in GetProperty of SoapObject

Tags: android, getproperty

Im trying to execute a return of soap and dont it shows a error in getproperty.

I tried of two ways.

1-

```
SoapObject obj, obj1;
obj = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
obj1 = (SoapObject) obj.getProperty("STRUCTSTK");

desc.setText(obj1.getProperty(1).toString());
prcrev.setText(String.format(obj1.getProperty(12).toString(), 0.00).toString());
saldo1.setText(obj1.getProperty(10).toString());
```

2-

```
SoapObject obj, obj1;
obj = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
obj1 = (SoapObject) obj.getProperty("STRUCTSTK");

desc.setText(obj1.getProperty("DESCPROD").toString());
prcrev.setText(String.format(obj1.getProperty("NPRCREV").toString(), 0.00).toString());
saldo1.setText(obj1.getProperty("LJ25GERAL").toString());
```

both not worked and show a `NullPointerException` in line of `desc.settext`...

Anyone can help me ?

Thks

Comment: Did you initialize `desc`?

Comment: have you checked coming value from web service in that particular property?

Comment: Hariharan i forgot to initialize the variable desc lol ... Thks all